# Concat 2 dynamic data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, concatenation

I want to concat two dynamic data using jquery, within the input field like this

```
<select id="trigger" name="country" required>
  <?php foreach($country as $c){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $c->name;?>"><?php echo $c->name;?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

<input id="autocomplete" type="text" name="street" required>
```

I have try using this script

```
$('#trigger').change(function(){
$('#autocomplete').val($('option:selected',this).text());
});
```

So, what I get is "Country" in the textbox of street, and i have to add the "Street" after the "Country". But if I change the "Country", the "Street" which I type earlier dissapear.

How can I change the "Country" and the "Street" without anyone vanish ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want country stacking up. You need to remove the country in the input box every time you change the select input. This is my code.

```
var temp = "";
$('#trigger').change(function(){
  var country = $("#trigger").val();
  var street = $("#autocomplete").val();
  var put = street.replace(" " + temp, "");
  temp = country;
  $('#autocomplete').val(put + " " + country);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$('#autocomplete').val($('option:selected',this).text());
```

To this:

```
$('#autocomplete').val($('#autocomplete').val()+$('option:selected',this).text());
```

Comment: The script add the "Country", can I just change it and not adding it more and more?